# TYPO3 - typoscript for extension plugin

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I would like to execute some typoscript commands only on page with a specific plugin on it :

```
page.includeCSS { }
page.includeJS { }
lib.my_bloc = COA
etc...
```

I move my typoscript code into the file typo3conf/ext/my_company_plugin/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt but it seems not to work. How to make it work ?

Furthermore, I'm not able to set a default storagepid for my module. I want all new entities to be stored in the same specific folder (uid 184 by the way) but my TS into setup.txt isn't effective and the pid in database is the page the user were on, not the 184.

```
#constant
module.tx_company_events.persistence.storagePid = 184

#setup
module.tx_company_events.persistence.storagePid = {$module.tx_company_events.persistence.storagePid}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to add typoscript for specific page plugin then you can use typoscript condition like below.

```
// if get your plugin parameters then below typoscript works
[globalVar = GP:tx_extension_key|var1 > 0]
  // write your typoscript
  page.includeCSS { }
  page.includeJS { }
  lib.my_bloc = COA
[end]

// FOr specific pageId
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 10]
  page.includeCSS { }
  page.includeJS { }
  lib.my_bloc = COA
[end]
```

Also For StoragePid, make sure you included TypoScript from your ext in Root template.

Comment: Here's the complete documentation on TypoScript conditions: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html - for applying settings to nested pages `PIDinRootline` might be interesting as well.
Side-note: Keep the amount of TypoScript conditions at a minimum since those are evaluated on every cached page dynamically and might reduce performance a bit. If these settings belong to a particular extension only, using `PageRenderer` and loading CSS/JS files there might be an option.